# Mostrar seção do usuário, em páginas jsp e servlet

Tags: java

Estou com uma aplicação feita em JSP e servlet que funciona da seguinte maneira:

Antes de visualizar o conteúdo do site o usuário tem que fazer um login, eu queria adiciona a seguinte função após o usuário logar com sucesso, exibir uma mensagem de bem vindo,nomedoLoginDoUsuario, ou seja recuperar o nome do usuário e exibir está mensagem no canto da tela.

Como fazer isso com java? Alguém poderia da uma luz?

Comment: O que você tem até então? Como está fazendo a autenticação, um filtro básico seu mesmo?

Comment: Isso o login e usuário no banco, e deixei a pagina de login como inicial , por exemplo, quando o usuário digita a pagina index do site, a pagina solicita o login, pedindo usuário e senha, caso o usuário esteja cadastrado ele entra com sucesso, ao entrar com sucesso eu quero mostra na parte esquerda bemvindo, mas o nome do login.. Um filtro básico mesmo.

Comment: Cria sessão? Bota o usuário na sessão e recupera o nome dele, com JSTL mesmo. Posta aí como está seu JSP + Servlet + Filter :)

Comment: Ainda nao tenho conhecimento em JSTL.